# Generating SOAP messages with attribute from C# code

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to generate the following SOAP message from C# code.

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3DCA13685AB558766615063665309446">
        <wsu:Created>2017-09-25T19:08:50.943Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-09-25T20:48:50.943Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3DCA13685AB558766615063665252595">
        <wsse:Username>prdIDXXXX</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXX</wsse:Password>
        <wsu:Created>2017-09-25T19:08:45.259Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
// SOAP header class
public class Security : SoapHeader
{
    public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }
    public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
}

public class Timestamp 
{
    public string Created { get; set;}
    public string Expired { get; set; }
}

public class UsernameToken
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
}
```

But this does not generate the Attributes which are present in the SOAP XML. For example: The "ID" attribute within the Timestamp field, or the "Type" attribute inside the Password field.

How can I generate the attributes in C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[XmlAttribute]` to render value of property as xml attribute.

```
public class UsernameToken
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
}
```